# ie11 should start new session every time when run with robot framework but it's unable start new session

Tags: session, internet-explorer-11, robotframework

I was trying to implement a robot framework automation test for a sign-in page.when I run with IE browser the session wasn't closing for the 1st user and the user is in login even after using "Delete All Cookies" keyword for the 2nd user.This is only happening for IE11 browser and rest of the browsers(chrome, Firefox and Edge) are working fine.

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Selenium2Library
Library           OperatingSystem

*** Variables ***
${url_google}     https://accounts.google.com/signin
${local_ie_driver}    
D:${/}PortableApps${/}SeleniumIEWebDriver${/}IEDriverServer.exe

*** Test Cases ***
Google for macarronada using IE
    Set Environment Variable    no_proxy    127.0.0.1
    Set Environment Variable    webdriver.ie.driver    ${local_ie_driver}
    Open Browser    ${url_google}    ie
    Sleep  2s
    Input Text  //*[@id='identifierId']  xxxxxxxx@gmail.com
    Click Element  //*[@id='identifierNext']/content
    Sleep  2s
    Input Text  //*[@id='password']/div[1]/div/div[1]/input   abc123xxx@
    Click Element  //*[@id='passwordNext']
    Delete All Cookies
    Close Browser
```

Any Idea ? Has anyone else seen this issue or similar with robot framework?

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer by default "shares" session between multiple windows and tabs. Try this option to open new Internet Explorer windows

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11-windows_7/new-session-shortcut-for-ie11/1b3e6408-abcd-4dea-8afa-acb7b15e8f71 (i.e., the -noframemerging command line argument for opening Internet Explorer windows). It worked for the situation I was having which is similar to the situation you are presenting.

Let us know if it worked for you.